# How does my xUnit test pass when I have Assert.Null(result) and Assert.NotNull(result)?

Tags: moq, xunit, autofixture

I refactored some tests in my solution from MSTest to xUnit. Even though all my tests passed using MSTest, there were some changes performed that made me wonder how everything was so easily passing during my refactor.

I put contradictory assertions at the end of a test and debugged. Even though the result looked like what I wanted it to look like (the object was null), it passed both Assertions. How is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

The following is my test. The naming is modified, because this is code I am working on at work, but the modifications end at simple replacing of words. I added comments to show some of my intentions as well as what happened when I debugged the test.

```
using AutoFixture.Xunit;
using Moq;
using My.Core.Project.Interfaces;
using My.Core.Project].Models;
using My.UI.Project.Factories.Sidebar;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Extensions;

[Theory, AutoData]
public async Task GetReturnedObject_NoReturnedObject_EmptyResult(Guid returnedObjectIdentifier, ReturnedObjectType setupObject)
{
    //Arrange
    var mockServiceClient = new Mock<IServiceClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    var returnedObjectIdentifierParameter = returnedObjectIdentifier.ToString(); //Parse logic in the method exists, so I had to make sure the input was not just any string
    setupObject = null; //I want the search in the method to not find anything.

    mockServiceClient.Setup(c => c.GetReturnedObjectById(It.IsAny<Guid>())).ReturnsAsync(setupObject);

    var factory = new Factory();

    //Act
    var returnedObject = await factory.GetReturnedObject(mockServiceClient.Object, returnedObjectIdentifierParameter); //returnedObject is NULL.

    //Assert
    Assert.Null(returnedObject); //Hovered over returnedObject. It's NULL.
    Assert.NotNull(returnedObject); //Hovered over returnedObject, again. Still NULL. THIS SHOULD FAIL!
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove some features from the test and see if you can still reproduce the issue? For example, it looks like AutoFixture only supplies a GUID and an object that subsequently gets nulled out. What happens if you remove those method arguments and change the `[Theory]` to a `[Fact]`?

Comment: I removed the test method parameters and changed the annotation to [Fact]. Did a successful clean and rebuild. Now, Visual Studio doesn't even pick up the tests in the Test Explorer.

Comment: I closed Visual Studio, reopened and reran test with Fact as an annotation and no parameters. It behaved the same way as when Theory and AutoData were used (it passed the NotNull check even though the object is null).

Comment: Please edit your question with the changes you made. As far as I can tell, this removes AutoFixture as a likely source of problems? If so, please also remove the *autofixture* tag.